# How to set up wfs-t service in Geoserver using openlayers from postgis data?

Tags: postgis, geoserver, openlayers-2, wfs-t

I published my postgis data layers into Geoserver.
I have enabled wfs in the edit workspace > services.
Still the "layer preview" does not show any options under wfs. See the image.[image]
How can we set up a wfst service using postgis data in Geoserver and see the map in a webpage or qgis?
Does the Geoserver include any example wms/wfs viewers within, (same as the examples folder within the openlayers) so that I can see the wms/wfs/wfs-t with multiple layer overlays? If not how can I add openlayers viewer pages in to Geoserver folder system.

(edited)
Then, where should I put the client files? Sothat I can access from http://localhost:8080/geoserver/ ?
**Which directory is the web root within the Geoserver installation?**

Comment: Generally you should have only one one question per post. Before you post it as a new question, please search on this site. This has been answered many times here.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have WFS for Grouped Layers.

Grouped Layers are an Geoserver specific service, which works as a Single WMS service containing multiple Layers. This is outside the scope of OGC standards, and it only returns images.

Having a vector group layer for multiple layers does not make sense.

You should be able to access the individual layers as WFS.

Comment: I cannot find a the way how a wfs be enabled for an individual layer, (I saw it there for the entire workspace), and to see the single wfs layer in openlayers from geoserver. Should I write separate html page for that? If yes, where I can put that page in and access in the localhost? Also how to get the wfs urls from Geoserver to add to openlayers?

Comment: Yes, the individual layers shows options under wfs, like Gml, GeoJson, kml, etc. But how can I use that output? I need to publish wfs with transactions that to be save to the postgis table.

Comment: geoserver does not come with a WFS client. You should just use your Geoserver's WFS endpoint in your client.

Comment: http://localhost:8080/geoserver/tiger/wfs?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=DescribeFeatureType&typeName=tiger%3Apoi   Is this the endpoint you mentioned(took from gml output)? Does this url can be displayed using openlayers and later be used for transaction also? Then where should I put the client files?

Comment: yes for all your questions.

Comment: Okay. But which folder is the webroot within Geoserver installation?

Comment: I used that url in qgis wfs client. It listed all three tables from the db in the table of contents, (even though the endpoint url has got only one layername) but with zero number of geometries. I have not given any filters.